# Make hubbub library for x32 and x64 platforms

Tags: gcc, makefile, x86-64

I need to make static hubbub library files for x32 and x64 platforms. Options like -m32/64 don't work, maybe I need to specify TARGET properly, but I don't know what to write here. What should I do?
Here is the makefile of the lib:

```
# Component settings
COMPONENT := hubbub
COMPONENT_VERSION := 0.2.0
# Default to a static library
COMPONENT_TYPE ?= lib-static

# Setup the tooling
PREFIX ?= /opt/netsurf
NSSHARED ?= $(PREFIX)/share/netsurf-buildsystem
include $(NSSHARED)/makefiles/Makefile.tools

TESTRUNNER := $(PERL) $(NSTESTTOOLS)/testrunner.pl

# Toolchain flags
WARNFLAGS := -Wall -W -Wundef -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align \
    -Wwrite-strings -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes \
    -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -pedantic
# BeOS/Haiku/AmigaOS have standard library errors that issue warnings.
ifneq ($(TARGET),beos)
  ifneq ($(TARGET),amiga)
    WARNFLAGS := $(WARNFLAGS) -Werror
  endif
endif
CFLAGS := -D_BSD_SOURCE -I$(CURDIR)/include/ \
    -I$(CURDIR)/src $(WARNFLAGS) $(CFLAGS)
ifneq ($(GCCVER),2)
  CFLAGS := $(CFLAGS) -std=c99
else
  # __inline__ is a GCCism
  CFLAGS := $(CFLAGS) -Dinline="__inline__"
endif

# Parserutils
ifneq ($(findstring clean,$(MAKECMDGOALS)),clean)
  ifneq ($(PKGCONFIG),)
    CFLAGS := $(CFLAGS) $(shell $(PKGCONFIG) libparserutils --cflags)
    LDFLAGS :=$(LDFLAGS) $(shell $(PKGCONFIG) libparserutils --libs)
  else
    CFLAGS := $(CFLAGS) -I$(PREFIX)/include
    LDFLAGS := $(LDFLAGS) -lparserutils
  endif
endif

include $(NSBUILD)/Makefile.top

ifeq ($(WANT_TEST),yes)
  # We require the presence of libjson -- http://oss.metaparadigm.com/json-c/
  ifneq ($(PKGCONFIG),)
    TESTCFLAGS := $(TESTCFLAGS) \
        $(shell $(PKGCONFIG) $(PKGCONFIGFLAGS) --cflags json)
    TESTLDFLAGS := $(TESTLDFLAGS) \
        $(shell $(PKGCONFIG) $(PKGCONFIGFLAGS) --libs json)
  else
    TESTCFLAGS := $(TESTCFLAGS) -I$(PREFIX)/include/json
    TESTLDFLAGS := $(TESTLDFLAGS) -ljson
  endif

  ifneq ($(GCCVER),2)
    TESTCFLAGS := $(TESTCFLAGS) -Wno-unused-parameter
  endif
endif

# Extra installation rules
I := /include/hubbub
INSTALL_ITEMS := $(INSTALL_ITEMS) $(I):include/hubbub/errors.h
INSTALL_ITEMS := $(INSTALL_ITEMS) $(I):include/hubbub/functypes.h
INSTALL_ITEMS := $(INSTALL_ITEMS) $(I):include/hubbub/hubbub.h
INSTALL_ITEMS := $(INSTALL_ITEMS) $(I):include/hubbub/parser.h
INSTALL_ITEMS := $(INSTALL_ITEMS) $(I):include/hubbub/tree.h
INSTALL_ITEMS := $(INSTALL_ITEMS) $(I):include/hubbub/types.h
INSTALL_ITEMS := $(INSTALL_ITEMS) /lib/pkgconfig:lib$(COMPONENT).pc.in
INSTALL_ITEMS := $(INSTALL_ITEMS) /lib:$(OUTPUT)
```

You also can download it:

```
 git clone git://git.netsurf-browser.org/libhubbub.git
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this:

```
$ make TARGET=amd64
```

or

```
$ make TARGET=i386
```